# Convert Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> to Spring's BindingResults or Errors

Tags: spring, bean-validation

How Can I convert from

```
  Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(obj);
```

constraintViolations to BindingResults/Errors.

Something like :

BindingResult result = constraintsViolations.toConvertBindingResult();

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a `bean` with type `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`. Add this to one of your configuration classes:

```
  @Bean
  public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
  }
```

Then autowire validator where you need it. You should use Spring's `Validator` interface instead of `javax.validation.Validator`. (Spring will autowire both if you need either):

```
 import org.springframework.validation.Validator

 @Autowired
  private Validator validator;
```

Now you can use the validator with BindingResult like this:

```
BindingResult bindingResult = 
new BeanPropertyBindingResult(myBeanObject, "myBeanObjectName");

validator.validate(myBeanObject, bindingResult);
```